# pass value to button for jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple buttons that gets created in a table which all look like this:

```
<button class="editbutton">Edit</button>
```

In this table the button will have a type associated with it, either APPLE or ORANGE.

What I want to do is pass in this type into my javascript to open up a jquery dialog.  I could do something like this:

```
<button class="editbutton" onclick="edit('<?php echo $result[$i]["type"]; ?>');" >Edit</button>
```

Then do the processing in the edit function now that I have the type.  But the way my code is structured I'm looking for a way to pass in the type without creating a function (just because the way I've structured the code).  So I need to know when the button clicked if it is the APPLE or ORANGE so I can open up a specific jquery dialog.

Hopefully it is clear what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attach a click listener to your button - http://jsfiddle.net/XPQ5Y/

```
<button class="editbutton" data-type="apple">Edit</button>

$(".editbutton").on("click", function() {
    var type = $(this).attr("data-type");

    // do your stuff here
});
```

Comment: @ZoltanToth: you can even go further with Jquery's data() syntax: var type = $(this).data('type');